# Generar carácter aleatoriamente sin repetir

Tags: javascript, random

Estoy generando una función que me genera aleatoriamente una cadena de caracteres de una longitud dada por el parámetro `num`:

```js
function generarRandom(num) {
  const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

  return result;
}
console.log(generarRandom(6));
```

pero no he podido hacer que no me genere caracteres repetidos.

Comment: Acá dejo un [Benchmark](https://jsben.ch/sgELk) de las respuestas

Comment: Todas las respuesta son muy buenas, pero recuerda que no podrás generar cadenas que no contengan caracteres repetidos para tamaños de cadena mayores a la cantidad de caracteres que dispones para formarlas, algunas respuestas fallan cuando se presenta este caso. La cantidad de caracteres que defines en tu pregunta es de 62, por lo tanto ese es el tamaño máximo de cadena que podrás generar sin que se repita ningún carácter.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! mauricio

Answer (score 9):

La mejor manera de asegurarte de que los elementos sean aleatorios y no repetidos es mezclar aleatoriamente la colección de elementos posibles.

Dicho de otro modo, es como repartir naipes de una baraja: barájala y luego toma los primeros N elementos.

```js
function barajar(array) {
  let posicionActual = array.length;

  while (0 !== posicionActual) {
    const posicionAleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random() * posicionActual);
    posicionActual--;
    //"truco" para intercambiar los valores sin necesidad de una variable auxiliar
    [array[posicionActual], array[posicionAleatoria]] = [
      array[posicionAleatoria], array[posicionActual]];
  }
  return array;
}





function generarAleatorios(cantidad) {
  const caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
  barajar(caracteres);
  return caracteres.slice(0,cantidad).join("")
}
console.log(generarAleatorios(5));
console.log(generarAleatorios(8));
console.log(generarAleatorios(62));
```

Comment: Buenas tardes pablo, realice la prueba... pero aun así me sigue generando valores repetitivos, lo que necesito es que primero me valide si el carácter ya se encuentra asignado, si se encuentra asignado que vuelva y active la función hasta que encuentre un valor que aun no ah sido almacenado y se ingrese.

Comment: Es imposible que se repitan caracteres. Si te refieres a que puede generar la misma contraseña dos veces entonces sí es posible, pero dependerá del tamaño de la misma.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar la funcion includes de la siguiente forma, e ir generando result solo si no contiene ya ese carácter.

```js
function generarRandom(num) {
    const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let result = "";
    let ch;
    while (result.length < num){
        ch = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        if (!result.includes(ch)){
            result += ch;
        }
    }
  return result;
}
console.log(generarRandom(6));
console.log(generarRandom(6));
console.log(generarRandom(6));
console.log(generarRandom(6));
```

Comment: Ya está, gracias Marcos.

Comment: Tu método falla si se piden cadenas de más de 62 caracteres, puedes leer [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474691/generar-car%c3%a1cter-aleatoriamente-sin-repetir#comment845598_474691) al respecto. Es para tomar en cuenta ese caso partilcular. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function generarRandom(num) {
  const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  if(charactersLength < num) return "error de longitud";
  let result = "";
   // hacemos un bucle while hasta que la longitud del string
   // sea menor a la de num
   while(result.length < num) {
      // guardamos la letra aleatoria
      let letra = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      // solo si no existe en el string la agregamos
      // indexOf retorna -1 si el elemento no existe
      if(result.indexOf(letra) === -1) result += letra;
    }

  return result;
}


for (let i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(generarRandom(6));
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Bryro, realice la prueba... pero aun así me sigue generando valores repetitivos, lo que necesito es que primero me valide si el carácter ya se encuentra asignado, si se encuentra asignado que vuelva y active la función hasta que encuentre un valor que aun no ah sido almacenado y se ingrese.

Comment: Tu método falla si se piden cadenas de más de 62 caracteres, puedes leer [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474691/generar-car%c3%a1cter-aleatoriamente-sin-repetir#comment845598_474691) al respecto. Es para tomar en cuenta ese caso partilcular. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma de verlo sería: Si los caracteres están en un arreglo y cada vez que buscamos un caracter lo sacamos, evitamos que se repitan.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function generarRandom(num) {
  // Convertimos la cadena en un arreglo
  let characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split(''),
    result = "";
  // Control de longitud
  if (num > characters.length) return false;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    // Lo agregamos al resultado y sacamos del arreglo
    result += characters.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length), 1)[0];
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(generarRandom(6));
console.log(generarRandom(62));
console.log(generarRandom(63));// Mas de los que hay
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Marcos, realice la prueba... pero aun así me sigue generando valores repetitivos, lo que necesito es que primero me valide si el carácter ya se encuentra asignado, si se encuentra asignado que vuelva y active la función hasta que encuentre un valor que aun no ah sido almacenado y se ingrese.

Comment: Tu método falla si se piden cadenas de más de 62 caracteres, puedes leer [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474691/generar-car%c3%a1cter-aleatoriamente-sin-repetir#comment845598_474691) al respecto. Es para tomar en cuenta ese caso partilcular. Saludos

Comment: No tira error, simplemente añade `undefined` al final de la cadena, luego la cadena a partir de la posición 62 contiene la palabra `undefined` por cada caracter adicional superior a 62 que pases como argumento. Prueba esto: `console.log(generarRandom(63).substring(62));`, pides generar una cadena de 63 caractes y desde la posición 62 debería haber 1 sólo carácter, pero devuelve la palabra `undefined`. ;)

Comment: @MauricioContreras, tenes razón! Ahí la actualice

Answer (score 1):

### Removiendo caracter elegidos

Es similar, pero esta vez vas removiendo los caracteres que ya tomaste con `.replace(char,'')`.

```js
function choose(choices) {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
      return String(choices[index]);
    }

    function generarRandom(num) {
      let characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      let result = [];
      let char;
      for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (characters.length==0){break;}
        char=choose(characters);
        characters=characters.replace(char,'');
        result.push(char);
        
      }
      return result.join('');
    }
    console.log(generarRandom(6));
```

### Opción con 'Set'

Podrías asegurarse que ningún elemento se repita aprovechando el objeto "Set" [Ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Tomo `randomChoice` de [random selection from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071573/is-there-a-simple-way-to-make-a-random-selection-from-an-array-in-javascript-or),

Repetir hasta que el tamaño sea 'n', elegir un caracter aleatorio, agrgarlo al set (que automáticamente elimina elementos repetidos).

**Nota de código no escalable: si fuese de 62 caracteres en el último tardaría en promedio 62 ejecuciones para elegir el que queda. Por lo que la eficiencia es baja.**

```js
function choose(choices) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  return String(choices[index]);
}

function generarRandom(num) {
  const characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  let result = new Set();
  while (result.size<num && result.size<characters.length){
  result.add(choose(characters));
    }
  return new Array(...result).join('');
}
console.log(generarRandom(6));
```

Comment: Perfecto, te agradezco la ayuda.. si me funciono

Comment: Tus dos métodos fallan para cadenas de más de 62 caracteres, puedes leer [mi comentario al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474691/generar-car%c3%a1cter-aleatoriamente-sin-repetir#comment845598_474691). Es para tomar en cuenta ese caso particular. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras He agregado las condiciones respectivas para que se salga del ciclo en caso de que llegue a 62 caracteres. El primer metodo es muy ineficiente considerando que para el último caracter la probabilidad de tomarlo es 1/62.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!